# preserving colors when piping yaourt through sort

Tags: pipe, colors, yaourt

Can sort preserve piped in colors? I'm trying to modify `yaourt -Qu | sort` so I get color output. Tried googling this but I couldn't find a general way nor a special way to do this for sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out yaourt has a color option, and `yaourt -Qu --color | sort` works.

Comment: It's not `sort` that removes the colors, it's `yaourt`. Unless told otherwise, like many programs, it only prints out in color when its output is on a terminal, not when it's a pipe (because piped output is usually for processing by a program).